# Representing the function EOF -> False, A -> A ∀ A ≠ EOF in Typed Racket?

Tags: types, racket, typed-racket

I am trying to define the type annotation for the following function in Typed Racket:

```
(define (neof x)
    (if (eof-object? x) #f x))
```

Leaving it un-annotated gives the type:

```
(Any -> Any)
```

Using this type produces an error:

```
(: neof (All (A) (case-> 
                  (EOF -> False)
                  (A -> A : #:+ (! EOF))))

  expected: A
  given: False
  in: #f
```

This is presumably because one can let `A = EOF` and then we get `EOF -> EOF`.

The type `(: neof (All (A) A -> (U A False) #:- (U EOF False)))`, while not as clear as the above, also gives errors:

```
 mismatch in filter
   expected: (Top | Bot)
   given: ((! (U False EOF) @ x) | ((U False EOF) @ x))
   in: (if (eof-object? x) #f x)
```

My goal was to have a function which I could apply to any output from a port an get either `False` or the value from the port.  I am now reconsidering the need for this, as I've blown way too much time trying to figure out this type.

For completeness, I also tried this definition of `neof`:

```
(define/match (neof x)
    [((? eof-object?)) #f]
    [((? (compose not eof-object?))) x])
```

(Also with the second pattern being `_`, but that doesn't encode the same amount of type information. At this point I'm more trying to appease the type checker than anything).

So: how can I represent the type of `neof`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the type you want is this:

```
(: neof (All (A) (A -> (U False A) :
                    #:+ (! EOF)
                    #:- (or EOF False))))
```

(The `#:-` clause is optional, I just included it there for completeness.)

***Note:*** If the `#:-` clause is included, it will *not* typecheck in Racket 6.1.1. Removing the clause will allow it to pass on 6.1.1.

The issue here is that all branches of `case->` must typecheck *independently* of one another. For the `(A -> A)` case, it fails because `#f` is not an `A`. The occurrence typing information from the first case cannot influence typechecking on the second case.

Comment: Your answer looked good, so I was really hopeful. Unfortunately, this is the result:

`Type Checker: type mismatch;
 mismatch in filter
  expected: ((! EOF @ x) | Bot) \n
  given: ((! (U False EOF) @ x) | ((U False EOF) @ x)) \n
  in: (if (eof-object? x) #f x)`

(\n's added by me, theyr'e newlines which comments can't have >.>)

Comment: @JDavidSmith Hmm, you're right, it doesn't typecheck for me on Racket 6.1.1. Typed Racket is currently in pretty heavy development, so this is something that only seems to typecheck on the snapshots. You could download a [snapshot build](http://pre.racket-lang.org/installers/) if you'd like—they're usually pretty stable. Otherwise, you may have to wait until the next release.

Comment: @JDavidSmith If you remove the `#:-` case, though, it will typecheck on Racket 6.1.1.

Comment: I just did that. Wonderful! Thanks!

Comment: It appears that this does not encode the fact that neof cannot return a value of type EOF. For now, I am happy with the fact that it passes the type-checker. I may try a snapshot tomorrow.

Comment: @JDavidSmith I think you might be missing the idea of what those propositions do. They deal with the *argument*, not the return value. Read up on the docs.